# Index 2 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 2

Tags: python, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to create a scatter plot using data from a .npy file, in the file there are 3 matrices each with two columns. When I try to run the code I get the following error: IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 2

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from RandomScan import iteration,i_sample




history_my_optimization = np.load("history_optimization.npy")

 plt.scatter(history_my_optimization[iteration,i_sample,0],
 history_my_optimization[iteration,i_sample,1],
 history_my_optimization[iteration,i_sample,2])

plt.xlabel = ("delay(um)")
plt.ylabel = ("Energy(MeV)")
plt.show()'
```

#iteration and i_sample come from another file and are basically column 1 and columns to in each matrix

Comment: What is the `history_my_optimization.shape`?

Comment: Please fix your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the comments on your question it's difficult to understand the problem without being able to reproduce it. However, I did see something in your question that caused me some suspicion.

You say your matrices have 2 columns. This means the first column can be reached with index `0` and the second column with index `1`. The error message says `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 2`. Somewhere in your code you are trying to access a matrix with index `2`, but this doesn't exist.

More specifically the error message states that you are out of bounds for axis 2, which you can interpret as the `z` dimension of you matrix (where `x` and `y` are dimensions `0` and `1` respectively).